# Using a browser extension to detect opening a specific site

Tags: browser, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, safari-extension

We have a web app and would like the browser to detect attempts to open a new link. A typical use case is the person has our app open; they click a link in their email - instead of opening this link in a new window we want to open an internal tab in our application.

Of course this is not possible without an extension; but is it possible with a browser extension for FF/Chrome/Safari/IE? We would need the extension to check the URL of a new tab being created against a simple match - and if there is a match to prevent the new tab from being created, run a js request in the tab we are using and switch the view to that tab.

Answer (score 1):

For Safari the answer is yes. You can listen for a `beforeNavigate` event. The event has a `url` property. If you then call `event.preventDefault()`, a new tab will not be created.

One potential problem is, you may not be able to distinguish between new tabs being opened by other apps (such as an email client) and those being opened by the browser itself (such as when a user command-clicks a link to open it in a new tab). If that matters to you.